# Identify (and disable) on-screen keyboard

Tags: windows-10, keyboard

Recently when streaming games to my Nvidia Shield from my Windows PC the pictured on-screen keyboard has started popping up. It constantly tries to steal focus from the controller, affecting the game to think I suddenly have switched from a controller to a keyboard. Problem is, I have no idea which application is launching the soft keyboard. To make matters worse, I can't interact it with if I try to from my PC (using the keyboard / mouse).

Does anyone recognize this *wonderful* keyboard application?

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That is the Steam controller keyboard. See this link for a few options how to disable it: https://steamcommunity.com/app/353370/discussions/0/358415738183388695/

Some of the posted suggestions:

> - In your Steam window: View ----> Settings ----> Controller ----> Desktop Configuration. This will open a window that displays your
>     controller. Click the box on the bottom left showing the various Arrow
>     Keys. It will show a few settings. On the right, click on "Show
>     Keyboard" under the "Click Action" setting. This will open up a
>     keyboard and mouse with a bunch of possible bindings. Click the
>     "Remove" button, below the keyboard display. Back out of the settings
>     and click 'OK This will unbind the stupid keyboard from popping up
>     when you press down on the stick.
> - Go into your Steam settings, and under "In-game" uncheck the box that says "Use the Big Picture Mode overlay when using a Steam
>     Controller from the desktop" Then, always launch [your game] from the
>     desktop.
> - If you'd like to get rid of this, go to [your game] in your steam Library, then right click on it and go to properties. At the bottom
>     left you'll see "Set launch options..." open that and then add in
>     `-NoKeyboardUI`. Press ok and play [your game] as you normally would.
>     This will revert it back to the normal chat box.

Comment: Thanks! Found the solution myself moments before your post. Didn't suspect Steam as I wasn't play a Steam game ... but guess it decided to launch itself regardless.